# ASP.net looping through table

Tags: asp.net, html-table

I was wondering if any one could help me out; I have a table which looks something like the following:

```
<table id="Table1" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><b>1.</b> Question 1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="border-width:5px;border-style:solid;"></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="left" style="width:1000px;"><input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Group1" value="Radio1" /><label for="Radio1">Answer1</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="left" style="width:1000px;"><input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Group1" value="Radio1" /><label for="Radio1">Answer2</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="left" style="width:1000px;"><input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Group1" value="Radio1" /><label for="Radio1">Answer3</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="left" style="width:1000px;"><input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Group1" value="Radio1" /><label for="Radio1">Answer4</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="height:30px;"></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><b>2.</b> Question 2</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="border-width:5px;border-style:solid;"></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="left" style="width:1000px;"><input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="Group2" value="Radio2" /><label for="Radio2">yes</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="left" style="width:1000px;"><input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="Group2" value="Radio2" /><label for="Radio2">no</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="height:30px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I go about looping through each group of radio buttons and getting the text of the selected radio button?

The code displayed above is created dynamically ... in my aspx file I have the following code:

```
   <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        </asp:Table>
```

Comment: This table doesn't appear to be running on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're starting with a barebones `<table>` in your markup page, and dynamically adding those `<input>` afterwards.

Consider taking this approach:

1. Add the `runat="server"` attribute to your table.
2. In the code where you're adding those `<input>` tags, add a new `RadioButton` control. Use an ID here that you can predict later. Perhaps you can use a `RadioButtonList` instead, if the choices are logically grouped!
3. It's unclear if you're manually adding those `<tr>` and `<td>` as strings. Consider the option of `new TableRow()` and `new TableCell()`. Then add the new `RadioButton` to the `TableCell.Controls` collection with `tc.Controls.Add(myNewRadioButton);`
4. In your postback code, simply refer to your `RadioButton` controls by `id`, or even loop through the `Controls` collection property of the `Table1`.

```
foreach (Control x in Table1.Controls)
{
    if (x.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton"))
    {
         if (((RadioButton)x).Checked)
         {
             //proceed.
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (x is RadioButton) how do i get the text from the selected radiobutton ??

Comment: @c11ada - Here's one way to determine if the RadioButton is selected.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the rows in ASP.NET (on the server side), you need to convert the table, rows and the cells to server control (using runat="server") and iterate through the controls in the table.

**EDIT :** :- If you are adding the rows, cells and radionbuttons following way, all of them will be the server controls (and are runat=server) so that you can access them the way I mentioned above:--

```
// Create new row and add it to the table.
TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
{
// Create a new cell and add it to the row.   
TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
rdb.ID = "rdb_" + cellCtr.ToString();
rdb.Text = "radio button";
rdb.GroupName = "rdbGroup";
tCell.Controls.Add(rdb);
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
}
```

**EDIT:-**

You can find the controls in each cell.Something like below:-

```
foreach(TableCell cell in tableRow.Cells)
{
      foreach(Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
      {
      if(ctrl is RadioButton)
      {
         if(ctrl.Selected)
          {
             string rdValue=ctrl.Text;
          }
      }
      }

}
```

Or If you want to iterate on the client side using Javascript, have a look [here](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=823170) and you dont have to apply runat="server".

Comment: the table is already set to runat server ... but all the radio buttons and groups are created dynamically ... so how do i go about changing all this to make sure all the controls which are created dynamically to runat server

Comment: I just edited my answer. Have a look and let me know If that works for you.

Comment: that is exactly how i am adding the radio buttons and the rows ... but the bit im stuck on is how do i loop through each one of the groups of radio buttons and get the text for each selected radio button ??

Comment: I just edited my answer for some code to access the selected radiobutton text.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all controls to server controls (by adding the runat="server" attribute). You can then programatically access what you need o. The server.

Comment: the table is already set to runat server ... but all the radio buttons and groups are created dynamically ... so how do i go about changing all this to make sure all the controls which are created dynamically to runat server